# Why am I receiving an error when running a cron job on the Facebook API?

Tags: cron, cron-task

I have made a Facebook auto post system using latest API and i want the index.php file to execute by cron job. But when cron job is run, it mails me this error and post to Facebook is not posted. But when i run the index.php on browser it runs very well.

Here is the error message that i am getting in email.

```
error setting certificate verify locations:
  CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
```

Now another point is that , If i execute a simple mail.php file which has only a php mail function , it works perfect and mail is sent every minutes or so.

I am using this code to run the cronjob

```
/usr/local/bin/php -q /home/USERNAME/public_html/index.php
```

Any idea about why Facebook auto post is throwing error while executing it through crone job?

Comment: facebook php sdk is shipped with CA keys file. Do you have one?

Comment: I have these three files in the Facebook library fb_ca_chain_bundle.crt, facebook.php, base_facebook.php , what is CA file?

Comment: so no one have answer for this problem here?